# Filebeat kubernetes discovery for certain namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I'm trying to limit my filebeat daemonset to collect logs only from certain namespaces.

According to the [official autodiscovery documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover.html#_kubernetes), I can define `namespace:` but it seems to be singular, not plural.

Is there anyway to limit the namespace but for several namespaces?

My current configuration looks like this:

```
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      node: ${NODE_NAME}
      namespace: backend
      hints.enabled: true
      hints.default_config:
        type: container
        paths:
          - /var/log/containers/*-${data.kubernetes.container.id}.log
      include_annotations: '*'
```

Comment: Have you tried using templates with conditions that matches two namespaces (as described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/efk-stack-on-kubernetes-part-2) in line 35)

Comment: @thomas looks like what I need, but I'm not sure what this template is, the documentation fails to mention it, and I'm not sure what to include in it other than the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading it looks that you can achieve your goal with [Hints based autodiscover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html#configuration-autodiscover-hints):

The hints system looks for hints in Kubernetes Pod annotations or Docker labels that have the prefix `co.elastic.logs`. As soon as the container starts, Filebeat will check if it contains any hints and launch the proper config for it. Hints tell Filebeat how to get logs for the given container.

So basically you enable the hints in your main configuration:

```yaml
filebeat.autodiscover:
  providers:
    - type: kubernetes
      hints.enabled: true
      add_resource_metadata.namespace.enabled: true
      hints.default_config.enabled: false
```

Then you can provide the hint for it in form of annotation:

```yaml
annotations:
  co.elastic.logs/enabled: 'true'
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer, however, I want to apply it to all pods on the namespace, adding this annotation to all of my deployments seems tedious.

Comment: This annotation placed on namespace will result the logs of all the pods in chosen namespace to be collected.